# How to adjust Pry's (Ruby REPL) command and output history size?

Tags: ruby, read-eval-print-loop, pry

I would like to know how I can increase the command and output history sizes in Pry. That would be the equivalents of `IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY]` and `IRB.conf[:EVAL_HISTORY]` in Pry config.

Pry's documentation of [config](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration#Config_history) and [history](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/History) don't seem to cover this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need to know where you've looked and what you've tried. Without that people trying to help you will repeat searches you've done, probably offer suggestions that you've already tried and, in general, waste their time and yours. So help us help you and tell us what you've already done to speed up the process.

Comment: @ the Tin Man Thanks for welcome, although I am not really new! I added some detail to align with policies.